# Capturing key value pairs from a url string with a regex pattern

Tags: php, regex, parsing, php-5.5

I'm trying to use regex to parse a string like the below:

```
/subject=hello±@text=something that may contain\@hello.com or a normal sla/sh±@date=blah/somethingelseI don't want to capture after the first/
```

into:

```
subject = hello
text =something that may contain\@hello.com or a normal sla/sh
date = blah
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to split the string after the first '/' by something like '±@' - and only that combination in that order.

I've looked around and at the minute have the below:

```
([^/±@,= ]+)=([^±@,= ]+)
```

But this doesn't match only '±@' - it matches either @ or ±.
It also doesn't cope with the escaped @. (Instead i get: `text= something that may contain\` ).

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you split using the regex `±@` you get the 3 terms you want

Comment: When I try it on http://www.regexr.com/ it doesn't split with a group of "±@" - it matches either ± or @ - does that make sense?

Comment: `[±@]` is not a group, it's a character class. try just `±@`

Comment: I'm not sure how to rewrite ([^/±@,= ]+)=([^±@,= ]+) to reflect that?

Comment: delete the square brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?:\/|(?<=±@))(.*?=.*?)(?:±@|$|\/(?!.*±@))
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/h6CdYD4ckU)

An important part is the negative look ahead after the trailing slash `/(?!.*±@)` - this means "match a slash, but only if `±@` *doesn't* appear in the input after it".

---

Given this input:

`/subject=hello±@text=something that may contain\@hello.com or a normal sla/sh±@date=blah/somethingelseI don't want to capture after the first/`

It produces matches whose group 1 are:

```
subject=hello
text=something that may contain\@hello.com or a normal sla/sh
date=blah
```

Comment: Great - That works. One day I'll get my head around how, but thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok - it works in Ruby. But it doesn't work in php 5 (which I'm using) or on regexr.com :(

Comment: My guess is PHP5 does't support `\G` (end of last match), so I've replaced it with a look behind. It still works on rubular (regexr.com is useless for testing (because it uses javascript which does not support look behinds). Try the latest edit

Comment: @simeon then perhaps you should tag your question as php.